# The error `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`

Tags: r

I have a code

```
    Eratosthenes <- function(n) {
  if (n >= 2) {
    sieve <- seq(2,n)
    primes <- c() 
    for (i in seq(2,n)) {
      if (any(sieve == i)) {
        primes <- c(primes, i)
        sieve <- c(sieve[(sieve %% i) ! = 0], i)
      }
    }
    return(primes)
} else {
  stop("Input value of n should be at least 2.")
    }
}
```

with the error `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`. However, everything seems perfect with `}`, but I don't what wrong. Could anyone be able to tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: are you really using rstudio? if you were, the problems should be obvious. Also copy and paste your code back into rstudio, it will do all the proper indenting for you and show you where the brackets start and end

Comment: Yes, but even after using the right manipulation I got the same error

Comment: take out the space wthin `! =`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be here: `sieve <- c(sieve[(sieve %% i) ! = 0], i)`. I'm assuming that you want "is not equal to", so should be `sieve <- c(sieve[(sieve %% i) != 0], i)`.

Here's the formatted code that works for me:

```
Eratosthenes <- function(n) {
  if (n >= 2) {
    sieve <- seq(2,n)
    primes <- c() 
    for (i in seq(2,n)) {
      if (any(sieve == i)) {
        primes <- c(primes, i)
        sieve <- c(sieve[(sieve %% i) != 0], i)
      }
    }
    return(primes)
  } else {
    stop("Input value of n should be at least 2.")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know R and I can't be a judge of your code, but aren't you missing brackets in your inner IF statement?

like this:

```
for (i in seq(2,n)) {
      if (any(sieve == i)) {
            primes <- c(primes, i)
            sieve <- c(sieve[(sieve %% i) != 0], i)
        }
}
```

Comment: lol, was going to say the same thing.  This is why proper indenting is important.

Comment: Sorry, but even after that I got the same error