# Coding the twin primes function

Tags: r, primes

We know that a twin prime is a pair of primes (x,y), such that y = x + 2. I want to create a function `Thatit()` which could list of all twin primes below `n`. In knowing that the function [Eratosthenes()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117754/the-error-error-unexpected-in) list prime numbers up to `n` (i.e. between 2 and n), how could I modify my code to get such function?

```
    Thatit <- function(n){
      twin <- c()
      twin2 <- Eratosthenes(n)
    for(i in twin2){
      if((i+2) in twin2){
        twin <- c(twin, "(", (i, i+2), ")")
      } else next()
    } return(twin)
}
```

Comment: First, check an element whether in your list, use `%in%`, not `in`.

Comment: Are you sure your code is working? From what I see, a closing `}` is missing. It is difficult to spot as the code is poorly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid for loop and have:

```
TwinPrimesLong = function(n) {

if (n < 5) stop("Input value of n should be at least 5.")

primesLessThanN = Eratosthenes(n)

#Combine differenced sets with original prime set
twinPrimeSet = cbind( (primesLessThanN-2) ,primesLessThanN)

#Keep only those rows where differenced numbers are also primes i.e. belong to prime set
twinPrimeSet = data.frame(matrix(twinPrimeSet[(primesLessThanN-2) %in% primesLessThanN,],ncol=2))

colnames(twinPrimeSet)=c("TwinPrime1","TwinPrime2")

cat("The twin primes less than n = ",n,"in row form are :\n")

cat(paste0("(",twinPrimeSet[,1],",",twinPrimeSet[,2],")",collapse=","),"\n")

cat("\n\nThe twin primes less than n = ",n,"in table form are :\n")

print(twinPrimeSet)

#If you wish to return,uncomment below
# return(twinPrimeSet)

}
```

**Updated:**

With `diff` it can be further simplified as

`(primesLessThanN[diff(primesLessThanN)==2],primesLessThanN[diff(primesLessThanN)==2]+2)`

```
TwinPrimesShort = function(n) {

if (n < 5) stop("Input value of n should be at least 5.")

primesLessThanN = Eratosthenes(n)


#Use diff function to compute difference with previous value and check if == 2
TwinPrime1 = primesLessThanN[diff(primesLessThanN)==2]
TwinPrime2 = TwinPrime1 + 2

#Keep only those rows where differenced numbers are also primes i.e. belong to prime set 
twinPrimeSet = data.frame(TwinPrime1=TwinPrime1,TwinPrime2=TwinPrime2)

cat("The twin primes less than n = ",n,"in row form are :\n")

cat(paste0("(",twinPrimeSet[,1],",",twinPrimeSet[,2],")",collapse=","),"\n")

cat("\n\nThe twin primes less than n = ",n,"in table form are :\n")

print(twinPrimeSet)

}
```

**Output:**

```
TwinPrimesLong(100)
#The twin primes less than n =  100 in row form are :
#(3,5),(5,7),(11,13),(17,19),(29,31),(41,43),(59,61),(71,73) 
#
#
#The twin primes less than n =  100 in table form are :
#  TwinPrime1 TwinPrime2
#1          3          5
#2          5          7
#3         11         13
#4         17         19
#5         29         31
#6         41         43
#7         59         61
#8         71         73
```

Comment: I'd like to keep in a the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

All twin primes, except the pair (3,5) have the form 6 *k* ± 1 for some *k*. Thus, to find the twin primes less than *n*, first compute the sieving primes less than sqrt(*n*), initialize a bit-array of length *n* / 4 so all values are True, then sieve twice. In the first sieving, the indices of the bit-array represent 6 *k* + 1 for *k* = 0, 1, 2, . . . , so for each sieving prime find the smallest 6 *k* + 1 that is a multiple of the sieving prime and sieve from that point. In the second sieving, the indices of the bit-array represent 6 *k* + 1 for *k* = 0, 1, 2, . . . , so for each sieving prime find the smallest 6 *k* + 1 that is a multiple of the sieving prime and sieve from that point. Bit-array locations that survive both sievings represent twin primes; you can calculate the two twin primes from the index. This algorithm is very fast; it's just the Sieve of Eratosthenes. I discuss the algorithm at [my blog](https://programmingpraxis.com/2012/04/17/twin-primes/).